# Send data to watchface on timer in the background

Tags: android, wear-os

I am trying to send DataItems to a watch face on a Handler timer in an Activity. but the problem is that when the activity loses focus, the Handler stops looping.

Is there a way to keep it running in the background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible with an Android service